# Min and max values on google charts ComboChart are being ignored left and right vAxis

Tags: javascript

I have seen an earlier question 7 year old now, and that refers to a chart with just the one verticle axis and uses the depricated

```
viewWindowMode:'explicit',
```

I have this chart

```
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Time');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Power (kW)');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Rate (p/kWh)');
    data.addRows([  [new Date(2022,11,12,0,0,0), 0.081, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,0,30,0), 0.079, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,1,0,0), 0.066, 11.43],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,1,30,0), 0.776, 11.43],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,2,0,0), 0.825, 11.43],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,2,30,0), 0.061, 11.43],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,3,0,0), 0.091, 11.43],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,3,30,0), 0.057, 11.43],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,4,0,0), 0.077, 11.43],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,4,30,0), 0.097, 11.43],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,5,0,0), 0.057, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,5,30,0), 0.078, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,6,0,0), 0.067, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,6,30,0), 0.064, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,7,0,0), 0.138, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,7,30,0), 0.191, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,8,0,0), 0.167, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,8,30,0), 0.276, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,9,0,0), 0.238, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,9,30,0), 0.199, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,10,0,0), 0.155, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,10,30,0), 0.205, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,11,0,0), 0.156, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,11,30,0), 0.154, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,12,0,0), 0.145, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,12,30,0), 0.261, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,13,0,0), 0.222, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,13,30,0), 0.192, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,14,0,0), 0.135, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,14,30,0), 0.165, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,15,0,0), 0.163, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,15,30,0), 0.168, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,16,0,0), 0.225, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,16,30,0), 0.2, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,17,0,0), 0.19, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,17,30,0), 0.209, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,18,0,0), 1.282, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,18,30,0), 0.361, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,19,0,0), 0.138, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,19,30,0), 0.122, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,20,0,0), 0.154, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,20,30,0), 0.181, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,21,0,0), 0.147, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,21,30,0), 0.189, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,22,0,0), 0.17, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,22,30,0), 0.14, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,23,0,0), 0.163, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,12,23,30,0), 0.134, 41.33],
    [new Date(2022,11,13,0,0,0), 0.197, 41.33] ]
);

    var options = {
         title: 'Company Performance',

        backgroundColor: '#EAEEFA',
        vAxis: { 0: {viewWindow:{min: 0.0, max: 15}},
                 1: {viewWindow:{min: 0.0, max: 50}}},
        series: {0: {type: 'bars', targetAxisIndex:0 },
                 1: {type: 'line', targetAxisIndex:1 }}};

        var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

And the left hand verticle axis max value is ignored, I suspect the right ne is as well as in jsfiddle it make no differenc what I change the max value in the second viewWindow object.
Is there a way to set the min and max values of the two vAxis that will be acted upon?

I have tried setting

```
viewWindowMode:'explicit',
```

but this did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh stupid me. when adding a second verticle axis the options property is no longer vAxis, but becomes vAxes! (a cas of I need to improve my english language): so the options above becomes :
var options = {
title: 'Company Performance',

```
    backgroundColor: '#EAEEFA',
    vAxes: { 0: {viewWindow:{min: 0.0, max: 15}},
             1: {viewWindow:{min: 0.0, max: 50}}},
    series: {0: {type: 'bars', targetAxisIndex:0 },
             1: {type: 'line', targetAxisIndex:1 }}};

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```